# In Scala, is it possible to insert commas via a regex to separate thousands in numbers?

Tags: regex, scala

In Scala, is it possible to actually insert commas via a regex to separate thousands in numbers where the comma definitely is not there to start with?

For example, I'd like to convert `30000.00` into `30,000.00`.

Comment: J, please read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure this is exactly what you need, but you can use this:

```
val formatter = java.text.NumberFormat.getNumberInstance
println(formatter.format(30000.00)) // prints 30,000
```

Answer (score -2):

This is not scala based answer.

You can use regex `\d{1,3}(?=(?:\d{3})+\.)` to find the matches and substitute each match with the same match plus an extra comma **`$0,`**.

See the [online demo](https://regex101.com/r/uANj21/1).

**Explanation:**

- `\d{1,3}` This matches a decimal character between  1  and  3  times
- `(?=` Positive lookahead starts

  - `(?:` This indicates a Non-capturing group

    - `\d{3}` matches a digit exactly 3  times
  - `)` end of Non-capturing group.
  - `+` matches the previous group one or more times
  - `\.` matches the character  `.`  literally
- `)` Positive lookahead ends.